# Getting parent object with the id of referenced documents

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I'm new to document oriented databases. I'm stuck with a simple problem:

I have to differents objects : Post and tag.

```
{
   "_id": "ObjectId("50dad56881000001")",
   "author":"Chuck Norris",
   "title":"Blah....",
   "tags": [
       DBRef("Tag", ObjectId("50dad564871000001")),
       DBRef("Tag", ObjectId("50dad564871000002")),
       DBRef("Tag", ObjectId("50dad564871000003"))
}
```

I need to find Posts by tags. I can't figure out how to do that with a array of referenced objects...

Here are my mapped objects :

```
class Tag
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="string") */
    protected $name;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="date") */
    protected $createdAt;
}

class Article
{
    /** @MongoDB\Id */
    protected $id;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="date") */
    protected $date;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="string") */
    protected $title;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="string") */
    protected $author;

    /** @MongoDB\Field(type="string") */
    protected $content;

    /** @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Tag", cascade="all") */
    protected $tags
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something suitable to answer my problem. But I'm not sure it's the best way to do it...

```
public function getPostsWithTag($tagId)
{
   $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
      ->field('tags.id')
      ->in(array($tagId)
      ->getQuery()

   return $query->execute();
}
```